# Issue with using shared libraries in C++ projects

Tags: c++, c, mongodb, gcc, shared-libraries

I am trying to change MongoDB's source and use functions from an external library. I have been able to change the build scripts (*SCons* files) and force the compiler to do extra linking with the libraries I am going to use. Although I am not facing any issues while compiling the source code and linking the object files, I face an odd error when starting *mongod*. Here is the message that I am receiving (immediately before the *mongod* process terminates):

```
./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: .1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I was able to fix this by moving the .so file of the library to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and rename it to .1, which is the path *mongod* expects to find the shared library. I don't know what is the cause of this problem, but everything is fine with other libraries such as *pthread*. Is there any specific solution for this problem? In other words, what should I do to make the executable program look for the library file in other locations using proper naming (not .1)?

Here is the output while LD_DEBUG=all mongod:

```
  4564: 
  4564: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  needed by ./mongod [0]
  4564: find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
  4564:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
  4564:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
  4564: 
  4564: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  generating link map
  4564:   dynamic: 0x00007f6ddccb7d50  base: 0x00007f6ddcaa0000   size: 0x000000000021c448
  4564:     entry: 0x00007f6ddcaa6cf0  phdr: 0x00007f6ddcaa0040  phnum:                  9
  4564: 
  4564: 
  4564: file=.1 [0];  needed by ./mongod [0]
  4564: find library=.1 [0]; searching
  4564:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
  4564:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.1
  4564:  search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib        (system search path)
  4564:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/.1
  4564:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.1
  4564:   trying file=/lib/tls/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/lib/tls/.1
  4564:   trying file=/lib/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/lib/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/.1
  4564:   trying file=/usr/lib/.1
  4564: 
  ./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: .1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found the solution for my problem. Thought it might be also helpful to others.

Basically, when you are using **make** to create shared libraries, you should define the .so file name. This was my case and I just set it to a proper value and everything is now working, at least I have fixed this error by doing so.

Looking it up in Google, I found that **-soname** option of **gcc** is designed to do so.